# How to define partially parameterize generic implicit class?

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

Is it possible to define partially parameterize generic implicit class ? For instance assume I have following class

```
  implicit class IoExt[L, R](val io: IO[R]) {
    def wrapped(errorCode: String): IO[Either[ProcessingResult[L], R]] = ???
  }
```

How can I defined something like

```
type IoExtLocal[R] = IoExt[String, R]
```

And have `IoExtLocal[R]` be available as implicit class ?

The motivation is to free client code from specifying type parameter every time `wrapped[](..)` is called. It gets very verbose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create another implicit class and import necessary one

```
  object ioExt {
    implicit class IoExt[L, R](val io: IO[R]) extends AnyVal {
      def wrapped(errorCode: String): IO[Either[ProcessingResult[L], R]] = ???
    }
  }

  object ioExtLocal { 
    implicit class IoExtLocal[R](val io: IO[R]) extends AnyVal {
      def wrapped(errorCode: String): IO[Either[ProcessingResult[String], R]] = 
        (io: ioExt.IoExt[String, R]).wrapped(errorCode)
    }
  }

  import ioExtLocal._

  trait SomeR
  val x: IO[SomeR] = ???
  x.wrapped(???)
```

Comment: Thank you @dmytro-mitin ! In your solution every call of `wrapped` instantiates new object. Also compiler produces two wrapper classes per type. Could you propose solutions to these two shortcomings ?

Comment: Thanks. I've reach same result as well. I'll accept your answer anyway. Could you please share your thoughts why Scala compiler doesn't produce value class call in example from my answer?

Answer (score 1):

After trying multiple solutions I've found that following works without instantiating helper class on every call to `wrapped`

```
trait IoExtTrait[L, R] extends Any {

  protected def io: IO[R]

  def wrapped(errorCode: String): IO[Either[ProcessingResult[L], R]] =
    io.attempt.map(_.leftMap(ex ⇒ FailureMsg[L](errorCode, Some(ex))))

  def wrappedT(errorCode: String): EitherT[IO, ProcessingResult[L], R] =
    EitherT(wrapped(errorCode))
}

implicit class IoExtLocalString[R](protected val io: IO[R]) extends AnyVal with IoExtTrait[String, R] {
  override def wrapped(errorCode: String) = super.wrapped(errorCode)
}
```

on the other hand following instantiates helper class on every call

```
implicit class IoExtLocalString[R](protected val io: IO[R]) extends AnyVal with IoExtTrait[String, R] {}
```

If anyone know why it happens please let me know. I'm on Scala 2.12.8 (same behavior with 2.13-RC1).

Further conversation at https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/11526 confirmed that allocation happens on both cases. Too bad.

Comment: "Universal traits allow basic inheritance of methods for value classes, but they **incur the overhead of allocation**." https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html#introduction

Comment: @dmytro-mitin But how come adding `override` function which does nothing fixes this ?